# Using dataframe rows as function arguements

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to automate some graphing, without resorting to traditional loops. I'm having difficulty figuring out how to pass the elements of a row of a dataframe as the arguments of a function. The function looks like:

```
makeline  <- function(df, var, date, ylab="",xlab="", title="", nbershade=TRUE) {
p <- ggplot(df, aes_string(x=date, y=var)) 
p <- p  + geom_line()

# do some other magical things 
}
```

Lets say I have a dataframe with a row as follows:

```
row1 <- c("corn","Price","Date")
```

Since corn is a dataframe ggplot choked on it as a character. Then I used corn without the quotes and since it is a dataframe with column names "Price" and "Date", I thought this would work:

```
mapply(makeline,row1[1],row1[2],row1[3])
```

Anyhow, I'm fumbling trying to figure out efficiently use this new function without resulting to looping through lists. Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: can you show `str(df)` or `head(df)`? I can't make any sense of how `corn` is a dataframe and part of a row...

Comment: adding the `df <- get(df)` as below gets me the right thing when feeding row1 with corn enclosed by "". Next to figure out how to pass a dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I would recommend this as a strategy, but you can use `get` to get the data.frame

```
makeline  <- function(df, var, date, ylab="",xlab="", title="", nbershade=TRUE) {
  df <- get(df)
  p <- ggplot(df, aes_string(x=date, y=var)) 
  p <- p  + geom_line()

# do some other magical things 
}
```

You may need to adjust the environment for `get` to work consistently, but it has `inherits 
= TRUE` which takes care of most things

```
data(mtcars)
data(diamonds)

Map(makeline, df = c('mtcars','diamonds'), var = c('cyl','x'), date = c('mpg','y'))
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. If I - as you do - pass the character vectors in directly, and use the `get` function for the df it works as I would like. I can even create and name the character vectors outside the `mapply`, however I seem not to be able to pass the vectors by referencing the colnames if the character vectors are bound together in a data frame. For example:

Comment: `data2 <- data.frame(rbind(as.character(row1),as.character(row2)), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` where `row2` is similar row vector as above. Then `mapply(makeline,data2$X1,data2$X2,data2$x3)` does not work so well. Clearly their is some issue in either the way the dataframe is put together, or the way I am trying to call the col vectors. The error I get is `Error in mapply(makeline, data2$X1, data2$X2, data2$x3) : 
  Zero-length inputs cannot be mixed with those of non-zero length`

Comment: @tjbrooks, It looks like you have a typo in your column names, `data2$x3` should be `data2$X3`. If you are using `mapply`, you will need to have `SIMPLIFY = FALSE`, that is why I used `Map`, which is a simple wrapper for `mapply(..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE)`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
mapply(makeline,get(row1[,1]),row1[,2],row1[,3])
```